# Upload lot of files to Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage, blobstorage

I have directory where is about **100 000+** subdirectories. In every subdirectory is from one to ten files. All files are **images** with *content type* = **image/jpeg**.

Together this files have size **over 54 GB**. Is there any chance to upload this files with structure

*/orders/1000000003/12345468878.jpeg*.

I know that BLOB is not hierarchical. I don't have Windows, i don't have Powershell, i don't have Visual Studio.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: MacOS - Macbook - Applu.

Comment: Hierarchical structure already solved in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183857/how-to-create-a-sub-container-in-azure-storage-location

Comment: You're asking for... a tool recommendation? General approaches? Opinions? Tool recommendation questions and opinion-soliciting questions are unfortunately off-topic for StackOverflow.

Comment: No, i am looking for a way, how to do this. There is lot of problems with classic methods with software MASE, CyberDuck... There are problems with API too. Performance is really low, when i am trying to use PHP and libraries from Microsoft Github.

Answer (score -1):

Use the full path of your files as blob names. To upload from Linux or Mac, you can use Azure CLI (available as an NPM package).

Answer (score -2):

Even though the structure is not hierarchical, you can "emulate" directories by adding `/`'s to the path name.

There are multiple clients available for Mac that support Azure Storage; my favorite is Cyberduck: https://cyberduck.io/ (free)

Comment: Honestly, pitching a given product as an answer isn't really an answer. And the question itself is off-topic, as it's soliciting... ideas? Tools? Approaches?

Comment: @DavidMakogon My answer is responding to the question. OP asked how to emulate directories and how to upload files. I suggested one client, saying it's my favorite but not the only one. I can agree the original question is malformed (and maybe off-topic), but my answer is not inappropriate.