# Get Blob directory name in azure storage in php

Tags: php, azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I want to create directory and sub directory in azure storage from php and get that directory. This is my code.

```
$blobRestProxy = ServicesBuilder::getInstance()->createBlobService($connection_string);


$content = fopen("abc.txt", "r");
$blob_name = "dir1/dir2/di3/myblob";

try {
    //Upload blob
    $blobRestProxy->createBlockBlob("mycontainer", $blob_name, $content);
}
catch(ServiceException $e){
    // Handle exception based on error codes and messages.
    // Error codes and messages are here:
    // http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/dd179439.aspx
    $code = $e->getCode();
    $error_message = $e->getMessage();
    echo $code.": ".$error_message."<br />";
}
```

I want to get directory "dir1".I checked that example [How to create a sub container in azure storage location](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3183857/how-to-create-a-sub-container-in-azure-storage-location).
But it's not in php. Can any one help me how can we create and get directory in azure from PHP code.

Comment: Would you mind explaining what you mean by `how can we create and get directory in azure from PHP code.`?

Comment: Means i want to create directory and in this many sub directory. As you look in the given link "content/blue/images/logo.jpg,
content/blue/images/icon-start.jpg,
content/red/images/icon-stop.jpg" and get this blobs with directory name. As example show in link "CloudBlobDirectory directory = 
        cloudBlobClient.GetBlobDirectoryReference(directoryName); " But it's not in php

Comment: So one thing is that blob storage doesn't support sub directories. As such you can't create a sub directory inside a container. You essentially create an illusion of a subdirectory by prefixing your blob name. In the example above, `content/red/images` is a blob prefix and the name of the blob is ` content/red/images/icon-stop.jpg`. That leaves searching for blobs in a directory. What you can do is perform search by prefix where you specify the name of the prefix and storage service returns all blobs that start with that prefix.

Comment: So how can we use prefix name for getting all blobs?

Comment: You can specify the prefix in `ListBlobsOptions` (https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Blob/Models/ListBlobsOptions.php).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`ListBlobsOptions`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Blob/Models/ListBlobsOptions.php) to set specially object when querying Blobs from container. Per your requirement, you can use the [`setDelimiter('/')`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Blob/Models/ListBlobsOptions.php#L116) of this options to set the delimiter as to separate the virtual directory from blob names.

And to use [`getBlobPrefixes()`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Blob/Models/ListBlobsResult.php#L194) to get the virtual directory names from [`ListBlobsResult`](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-php/blob/master/src/Blob/Models/ListBlobsResult.php) which is the result of `listBlobs()` function.

Please consider the following code snippet:

```
use MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\ListBlobsOptions;
$listBlobsOptions = new ListBlobsOptions();
$listBlobsOptions->setDelimiter('/');
$result = $blobClient->listBlobs(<container_name>, $listBlobsOptions);
foreach ($result->getBlobPrefixes() as $k => $b) {
    //an instance of MicrosoftAzure\Storage\Blob\Models\BlobPrefix
    array_push($return['blobPrefixes'], $b->getName());
}
```

And here is a sample about how to use the modules in Azure Staoge SDK for PHP. You can have a full glance of the usage from https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blob-php-webapplication/blob/master/PHP/api/trial.php#L163.

Any further concern, please feel free to let me know.