# Have multiple names for same blob content

Tags: azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

Let's say I have a file called `foo.txt` in my Azure Storage as a blob. Is it possible for creating a `link` of sorts or a redirect url where I can access `foo.txt`'s content even when I visit `bar.txt`?

Ideally I do not want to upload the same file content again for `bar.txt` too to avoid wasting space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you can't. Azure Blob Storage is just simple object storage, not a full file system having soft links or hard links.

BTW, you may consider simulating the link feature following answers here: [Is there a way to do symbolic links to the blob data when using Azure Storage to avoid duplicate blobs?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7641316/is-there-a-way-to-do-symbolic-links-to-the-blob-data-when-using-azure-storage-to)