# readonly access to azure storage account

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-table-storage, readonly

Our software uses Azure blob & Azure table storage.

I would like developers to be able to look through our production data with the Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer, but not be allowed to accidentaly edit it's data.
I don't want to allow anonymous access to the data (read only) as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179695/how-do-i-define-a-read-only-access-connection-string-for-a-container-in-azure).

What would be a good way to achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make use of Shared Access Signature option to connect to Azure Blob Storage from the Storage Explorer.

Find more details about [SAS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/delegate-access-with-shared-access-signature) here.

Find more details about [SAS in Storage Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows#generate-a-sas-in-storage-explorer) here.
[image]