# How to create an empty text file inside my blob container

Tags: c#, azure-blob-storage

How to create an empty text file ( or text with some message )inside my blob container

```
var destBlob = blobClient.GetBlobReference(myblob);
```

something like 
https://myxyzstorage.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer/newfolder/newTextfile.txt

Comment: Just set your blob name "newfolder/newTextfile.txt".

http://stackoverflow.com/a/2624427/1384539

Answer (score 5):

If you are using a newer version of Windows Azure Storage Client Library, you should create a container and then use it to get a blob reference with the path you’d like your blob to have within the container. To create a path similar to the one you posted:

```
CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(“mycontainer”);
container.CreateIfNotExists();

CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("newfolder/newTextfile.txt");
blob.UploadText("any_content_you_want");
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using .NET standard, this code should work.

```
CloudBlockBlob blob = blobContainer.GetBlockBlobReference("File Name");

blob.UploadTextAsync("<<File Content here>>");
```

Answer (score 0):

The following example from [here](http://www.jayway.com/2011/10/18/azure-blob-storage-a-simple-example/) helped me to solve this

```
public Uri UploadBlob(string path, string fileName, string content)
{
    var cloudBlobContainer = cloudBlobClient.GetContainerReference(path);
    cloudBlobContainer.CreateIfNotExist();

    var blob = cloudBlobContainer.GetBlobReference(fileName);
    blob.UploadText(content);

    return blob.Uri;
}
```

Comment: Only comment I would have is to always have a retry policy in Production.  The storage client library includes this capability and can make weird/intermittent errors go away (espcially in a high volume prod enviornment): http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazurestorage/archive/2011/02/03/overview-of-retry-policies-in-the-windows-azure-storage-client-library.aspx