# Why doesn't Azure API list the blobs that is named /folder/folder/file?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I wanted to create folders and sub-folders, I found [this workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2624427/6197785): 
but when I listed them: using this code ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-blobs#list-the-blobs-in-a-container)):

```
foreach (IListBlobItem item in Container.ListBlobs(null, false))
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlockBlob))
                {
                    CloudBlockBlob blob = (CloudBlockBlob)item;

                    Console.WriteLine("Block blob of length {0}: {1}", blob.Properties.Length, blob.Uri);

                }
                else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudPageBlob))
                {
                    CloudPageBlob pageBlob = (CloudPageBlob)item;

                    Console.WriteLine("Page blob of length {0}: {1}", pageBlob.Properties.Length, pageBlob.Uri);

                }
                else if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudBlobDirectory))
                {
                    CloudBlobDirectory directory = (CloudBlobDirectory)item;

                    Console.WriteLine("Directory: {0}", directory.Uri);
                }
            }
```

It only shows parent folders and blobs in the root container.
I was expecting to get them all as blobs since this is virtual directory not real,
for example I have this file

```
https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/Accounts/Images/1/acc.jpg
```

but it doesn't show, it just show:

```
https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/Accounts
```

and

```
https://account.blob.core.windows.net/container/anyfile
```

Do I have to request sub-folders inside parent folders to reach the file?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please try by specifying 2nd parameter as `true` in [`ListBlobs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobcontainer.listblobs.aspx) method. This parameter indicates if you want flat blob listing (true) or hierarchical blob listing (false).

From the documentation link:

> *useFlatBlobListing*
>
> Type: System.Boolean
>
> A boolean value that specifies whether to list blobs in a flat
>   listing, or whether to list blobs hierarchically, by virtual
>   directory.

Answer (score 0):

If someone is looking for such flat file listing with the latest Azure.Storage.Blobs SDK, this is how you do it:

```cs
BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(connectionString);
BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient = blobServiceClient.GetBlobContainerClient(resource.Name);
var blobItemList = blobContainerClient.GetBlobs(); // This will get blobs without any hierarchy
```