# Azure: app to upload folders to azure portal

Tags: c#, .net, azure, winforms, azure-devops

I'm developing a small app in winforms using dotnet 5 to upload files to a container in the azure portal.. by the way it's working fine, but now i'd like to develop a service to upload a folder (not a single file), but cant figure out how to do it. It's not like to upload files. Somehow it's different and I've been looking for it for so long but cant find a solution.

Does anyone have an ideia?

Cheers

Comment: Does the below answer help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are trying to upload an entire folder through your service programmatically, note that it is not supported.

*Simply, you can create your blob called `folder/1.txt` for example, and it will work. No need to create a directory.* So, to sum it up, you can create a folder like this and start uploading your files in that folder.

Check out [Microsoft Azure: How to create sub directory in a blob container](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2619007/microsoft-azure-how-to-create-sub-directory-in-a-blob-container) for more details.

Comment: Did not know that wasnt supported. BTW I think I found a solution, which is the link below.
https://learn.microsoft.com/pt-br/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-scalable-app-upload-files?tabs=dotnet

Comment: Yes, but it will not create folder, It will upload blobs parallely.

Comment: Hey sir.. at the end we here decided to use your suggestion. That's exactely the way we need. Thank so much sir.